# How to handle DragGesture and PencilKit in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to figure out how I can add a drag gesture to a view that contains a `PKCanvasView` and allow drawing and dragging. I have the following views:

```
struct DrawingView: View {
    @State private var dragState = CGSize.zero
    @State private var translation = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        let longPressGesture = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                self.translation = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                self.dragState.width += value.translation.width
                self.dragState.height += value.translation.height
                self.translation = .zero
            }
        
        let longPressDrag = longPressGesture.sequenced(before: dragGesture)

        CanvasView()
            .offset(x: dragState.width + translation.width, y: dragState.height + translation.height)
            .gesture(longPressDrag)
    }
}

struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var canvas = PKCanvasView()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvas.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        return canvas
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {}
}
```

With the gesture added to `CanvasView`, I'm unable to draw. Naturally, if I remove the `longPressDrag` gesture, drawing works as expected. Seems that the `DragGesture` is conflicting with the PencilKit in some way (is it implemented internally as a `DragGesture`?). As seen above, I tried to initially get around this by having the drag gesture preceded by a long press, to no avail. Will I need to somehow need to reconcile this with a custom gesture recognizer? Is it possible to disable to have the drag gesture disabled until the long press is activated? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You have your canvas set to `.anyInput`. I'm a little confused about how the system could ever differentiate between drawing on the canvas or dragging it, even with the long press. It might be worth experimenting with pencil-only input, but even then, I'd be pretty skeptical if it were to work.

Comment: That's a fair point. Thanks for the suggestions.